# Page Elements Indenting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form where I have certain elements show/hide based upon a select box. That part is working perfectly for me. The problem I am having is that the elements inside the section that is originally hidden are indented when they show and I cannot figure out why. I am sure it has something to do with my CSS. I have tried adding `.register form section input...` in with the `.register form input...` but that made no difference. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$('section').hide()
$('#user_level').change(function() {
  var value = this.value;
  $('section').hide()
  $('#' + this.value).show();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  background-color: #f3f4f7;
}

body.loggedin {
  background-color: #f3f4f7;
}

.register {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.register h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #5b6574;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}

.register form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.register form label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3a4b3b;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.register form input[type="password"],
.register form input[type="text"],
.register form input[type="email"],
.register form select {
  width: 310px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.register form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #3a4b3b;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.register form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #537a56;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #3a4b3b;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: #eaebed;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.select-css {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding: .6em 1.4em .5em .8em;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: right .7em top 50%, 0 0;
  background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
}

.select-css::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.select-css:hover {
  border-color: #888;
}

.select-css:focus {
  border-color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(59, 153, 252, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px -moz-mac-focusring;
  color: #222;
  outline: none;
}

.select-css option {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="register">
  <h1>Add User</h1>
  <form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="first_name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
    <label for="last_name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
    <label for="email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    <label for="user_level"><i class="fas fa-user-tag"></i></label>
    <select class="select-css" name="user_level" id="user_level">
      <option value="0" selected disabled>User Type</option>
      <option value="1">Student</option>
      <option value="2">Faculty/Staff</option>
      <option value="3">System User</option>
      <option value="4">System Administrator</option>
    </select>
    <section id="1">
      <label for="grade"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label><input type="text" name="grade" id="grade" placeholder="Grade">
    </section>
    <section id="2">
      <label for="division"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>
      <select class="select-css" name="division" id="division">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Division</option>
        <option value="1">Central Office</option>
        <option value="2">Elementary School</option>
        <option value="3">Middle School</option>
        <option value="4">High School</option>
      </select>
    </section>
    <section id="3">
      <label for="division"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>
      <select class="select-css" name="division" id="division">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Division</option>
        <option value="1">Central Office</option>
        <option value="2">Elementary School</option>
        <option value="3">Middle School</option>
        <option value="4">High School</option>
      </select>
      <label for="user_name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="User Name">
    </section>
    <section id="4">
      <label for="division"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>
      <select class="select-css" name="division" id="division">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Division</option>
        <option value="1">Central Office</option>
        <option value="2">Elementary School</option>
        <option value="3">Middle School</option>
        <option value="4">High School</option>
      </select>
      <label for="user_name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="User Name">
    </section>
    <input type="submit" value="Add User">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because when you call `show()` it sets `display: block` on the `section` elements. This is a problem because they need to be `display: flex` as per the rest of your HTML structure.

To fix this create a CSS class to set the display setting and then use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` istead of `hide()` and `show()`:

```
$('#user_level').change(function() {
  $('section').removeClass('show')
  $('#' + this.value).addClass('show');
});
```

```js
section {
  display: none;
}

section.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

Here's the full working example:

```js
$('#user_level').change(function() {
  $('section').removeClass('show')
  $('#' + this.value).addClass('show');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  background-color: #f3f4f7;
}

body.loggedin {
  background-color: #f3f4f7;
}

.register {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 100px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

.register h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #5b6574;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}

.register form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.register form label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3a4b3b;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.register form input[type="password"],
.register form input[type="text"],
.register form input[type="email"],
.register form select {
  width: 310px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.register form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #3a4b3b;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.register form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #537a56;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #3a4b3b;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: #eaebed;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.select-css {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding: .6em 1.4em .5em .8em;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: right .7em top 50%, 0 0;
  background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
}

.select-css::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.select-css:hover {
  border-color: #888;
}

.select-css:focus {
  border-color: #aaa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(59, 153, 252, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px -moz-mac-focusring;
  color: #222;
  outline: none;
}

.select-css option {
  font-weight: normal;
}

section {
  display: none;
}
section.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="register">
  <h1>Add User</h1>
  <form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <label for="first_name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
    <label for="last_name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
    <label for="email"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    <label for="user_level"><i class="fas fa-user-tag"></i></label>
    <select class="select-css" name="user_level" id="user_level">
      <option value="0" selected disabled>User Type</option>
      <option value="1">Student</option>
      <option value="2">Faculty/Staff</option>
      <option value="3">System User</option>
      <option value="4">System Administrator</option>
    </select>
    <section id="1">
      <label for="grade"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></label><input type="text" name="grade" id="grade" placeholder="Grade">
    </section>
    <section id="2">
      <label for="division"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>
      <select class="select-css" name="division" id="division">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Division</option>
        <option value="1">Central Office</option>
        <option value="2">Elementary School</option>
        <option value="3">Middle School</option>
        <option value="4">High School</option>
      </select>
    </section>
    <section id="3">
      <label for="division"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>
      <select class="select-css" name="division" id="division">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Division</option>
        <option value="1">Central Office</option>
        <option value="2">Elementary School</option>
        <option value="3">Middle School</option>
        <option value="4">High School</option>
      </select>
      <label for="user_name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="User Name">
    </section>
    <section id="4">
      <label for="division"><i class="fas fa-building"></i></label>
      <select class="select-css" name="division" id="division">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Division</option>
        <option value="1">Central Office</option>
        <option value="2">Elementary School</option>
        <option value="3">Middle School</option>
        <option value="4">High School</option>
      </select>
      <label for="user_name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="User Name">
    </section>
    <input type="submit" value="Add User">
  </form>
</div>
```

As a side note, if a group of elements should be hidden when the page loads always set them as hidden in CSS. Doing it in JS means that they may be visible for a short time when the page loads and then suddenly disappear.